# Recording and saving sounds from applications?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, audio-recording

I Would like to make an appliaction in c# (or vb.net) that records every sound that comes out from the speakers when i tell it to, and when im finished i want to push a button and save it as an mp3 (or some other format).

So far i have only found APIs that can record something from a microphone.

My Question is: 
Is there anything in the .NET framework or is there some API for making this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen much on sound recording from the soundcard purely from the .NET framework, but you may find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Mp3SoundCapture.aspx) interesting. There are libraries such as [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org) and [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com) that work with .NET and may provide you with the ability to record the sound coming out the speakers. I came across [this thread for BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=10238.0;hl=record+speakers), but I'm not sure if that's of any use.