# Can we record sound sent to speakers using C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio, audio-recording

I have a software 'SoundTap Streaming Audio Recorder'.

It records any audio sent to speakers whether stream is coming from web or from some file or microphone. Can i make such app in desktop app having facility that i can record stream sent to my speakers regardless of source.?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582505/recording-and-saving-sounds-from-applications

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211484/how-do-i-capture-the-audio-that-is-being-played

Comment: As far as I know, yes. don't know how to be honest, but I think the Win32 API is a good place to start the research.

Comment: Check this also: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4889/A-full-duplex-audio-player-in-C-using-the-waveIn-w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31356/C-MP3-Sound-Capturing-Recording-Component

Answer (score 0):

> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/550be4bd-22da-4e6c-99d1-1a07016d659f/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can
even i have not same but smiler project
and my team is using NAudio. 
that part is not completed yet if it is then 
i will surely mail u sample code.

Regards Red ,